# Get erc-20 token balance inside token

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I as a owner sent some tokens TESTTOKEN to the token address.
I am a little bit confused how can i check the balance of tokens inside the token contract itself not the owner.

```
contract ERC20 {
function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
```

}

mycontract TESTTOKEN.. {

how can i check the balance here should i get the instance of ERC-20 token within token itself?

should i use  function address(this).balance or it returns eth not tokens i got confused about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `balanceOf(address)` method is most likely a getter to a `mapping(address => uint256)` property, the property is probably named `balances`.

So to get the **`THETOKEN` token** balance (not ETH balance) of this `THETOKEN` contract, you need to get the value of `balances[address(this)]`.

```
function getThisAddressTokenBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[address(this)];
}
```

Comment: so we dont use the erc-20 function balanceOf?

Comment: You can also use the `balanceOf()` function to get *any* address's token balance... The way I originally understood your question, was that you're asking how to get specifically this contract's balance outside of the `balanceOf()` function.